# Django,referring objects with double underscore

Tags: python, django

I have a function in the view file of Django Rest Framework project.
 Where it filters out *comments* (A model) with related to the specific *Post*

```
 class CommentListCreate(APIView):
    def get(self, request,pk):
        comment = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=pk)
        serializer = CommentSerializers(comment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The above function is able to filter according to the post_id, but if I change filter arguments as mention below

```
 def get(self, request,pk):
        comment = Comment.objects.filter(post__id=pk)
```

The function works fine, why do we use double underscore to refer the the post id ?

Git Link to my views.py https://github.com/Anoop-George/DjangoBlog/blob/master/blog/views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `ForeignKey`, you can use *both*. The first `post_id` is the "twin field" Django makes for a `ForeignKey` (this has a name with an `_id` suffix), and stores the value of the *primary key* of the record it refers to (or another *unique* field if you specify that in the `to_field` parameter).

If you want to look "through" a relation, you use double underscores (`__`). So you can refer to it with `post__id` as well.

If you however want to filter based on the `title` of the `Post` object, you query with:

```
comment = Comment.objects.filter(post__title='some title')
```

You can not use a single underscores, since a `ForeignKey` only makes a twin-field to store a reference, it does not make a `post_title` field to store the title of the referred `Post` object (that would not be a good idea, since it introduces *data duplication*).

Answer (score 3):

We use a double underscore to refer to the property of some related object in a django query. You can think of it in a similar way, to how you would think of a dot, chaining together properties.

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

    engine = models.ForeignKey('Engine', ...)

class Engine(models.Model):
    ...
    engine_size = models.IntegerField()
    engine_make = models.ForeignKey('EngineMake', ...)

class EngineMake(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField()
```

Now if I wanted to filter to find all cars with an engine made by a particular company, to go through the related fields, I can use a double underscore, such as follows:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(engine__engine_make__company_name="something")
```

In your case, you don't really need a double underscore, as when you add a ForeignKey, Django automatically adds a field called `foo_id`, if you add a foreign key called `foo` for example.

Comment: Thanks,much appreciate it